# Characterization of finite groups using sum of the orders of their elements

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

**Notation:** If $G$ is a finite group, $o(g)$ denotes the order of the element $g\in G$.

**Motivation:** Some finite groups could be uniquely determined by the *size of the group*. For example given a prime number $p$ there is just one group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ up to isomorphism. As there are infinitely many prime numbers, the number of finite groups that are completely determined with their size is infinite.

On the other hand there are finite groups that could be uniquely determined by the *sum of the orders of their elements*. For example $A_5$ is the unique finite group $G$ with $\Sigma_{g\in G}o(g)=211$ (see [this paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870802502530) by Habib Amiri, S. M. Jafarian Amiri & I. M. Isaacs).

Inspired by this fact the following question arises:

> **Question:** For which natural numbers like $n$, there is a unique finite group up to isomorphism with $n=\Sigma_{g\in G}o(g)$? Is there infinitely many such natural numbers?

Comment: I find this question very artificial: why would someone care about the sum of the orders of the elements? On the other hand, the related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39848/finite-groups-with-elements-of-the-same-order is much more natural.

Comment: In case you learnt that fact about $A_5$ and $211$ from the paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927870802502530  by Amiri, Jafarian Amiri and Isaacs, it would have been fair to mention it. In view of this paper and similar ones, I have to say @TomDeMedts that I do not find the question *particularly* artificial.

Comment: @FriederLadisch Thanks for reminding the reference. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: On the other hand, I agree that the question is not very natural either in the sense that I don't expect that there is any good reason (providing insight) why some $n$ like $n=211$ or $n=453$ determine the group up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 6):

A [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) calculation shows that the numbers $n \leq 512$ such that
there is up to isomorphism a unique finite group whose sum of element
orders is $n$ are as follows:

```
1, 3, 11, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25, 27, 33, 39, 45, 49, 57, 59, 61, 71, 73, 77, 83, 
97, 99, 101, 105, 113, 115, 125, 129, 153, 161, 163, 167, 173, 185, 189, 193,
203, 209, 211, 227, 249, 253, 259, 265, 275, 277, 289, 291, 307, 309, 321, 345,
357, 361, 377, 381, 393, 395, 397, 405, 407, 419, 425, 453, 481, 501, 507.
```

Among these numbers, only for $n = 211$ the corresponding group is
not solvable.

Comment: I can confirm the list :) (by running through the Small Groups Library for groups of order $\leq 255$).

Answer (score 5):

As a counterbalance to the question,  note  that for any odd prime $p$, there are two non-isomorphic groups of ordér $p^{3}$ with sum of element orders $p^{4} -p+1$.
Any $p$-group with that element order sum has order at most $p^{3}$. Groups of exponent $p$ are dealt with, and a $p$-group with more than one cyclic subgroup of order $p^{2}$ has element order sum too large- likewise for a $p$-group of order $p^{3}$ with a unique subgroup of order $p^{2}$. Cyclic $p$-groups are easily dealt with. So there are no more $p$-groups with that element order sum.