# What groups should I test my conjecture on?

Tags: gr.group-theory, conjectures

I have a conjecture that a certain criterion is enough for two groups to be isomorphic. I tested it on all pairs of groups up to size 12, and it worked like a charm. I know, however, that groups are strange and that it is very likely that my conjecture will break for larger groups. I have made myself a python library that handles making groups and seeing they have certain properties/are isomorphic, but I do not know what pairs of groups to test my conjecture on.

> What groups form a "representative sample" of all groups? What paris of groups would it be absolutely crucial for me to test my hypothesis on?

I don't see the need for any answer to be complete, but any ideas for pairs that would be interesting to test on would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The conjecture is that if two groups have the same count of elements of every order, then they must be isomorphic. I proved this for abelian groups, and am now wondering if it is true in general.

Comment: if you can't disclose the conjecture it is unlikely a helpful answer can be given.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you for your input, I edited the question.

Comment: (You seem to write "count" instead of "number" and "degree" instead of "order"?) There are two non-isomorphic groups of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, for odd $p$.

Comment: "What groups form a "representative sample" of all groups?": the answer depends on the question, but typically: groups of small order, $p$-groups of small order (which here give maybe the easiest examples, order 27, although order 16 might too, yet more complicated by hand). If you learn GAP, you can quickly make such tests for groups, say of order $\le 100$.

Comment: Although your specific conjecture has been addressed, and the question of *exactly* which groups to test will vary, I think it's fair to say the answer of "how should I use my algorithm?" is "don't."  As @YCor says, GAP knows many small groups, and is tuned to work with them in an efficient way.  With no insult meant to your programming abilities, it is likely that GAP will be far faster, so it'll matter less which groups exactly you test, since you can test more of them.

Comment: @NickS Maybe I made an error in my calculations since I did them by hand. This was one of the reasons why I wanted to switch to systematic testing on a computer.

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure where you're getting the groups of $3$ elements of order $4$ from (we only get blocks of $p-1$ elements of order $p$ when $p$ is prime). If I'm not mistaken the order profiles of $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, D_8, Q_8$ are $\{ 1, 2^3, 4^4 \}, \{ 1, 2^5, 4^2 \}, \{ 1, 2, 4^6 \}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My mistake, I forgot that the orbit of an element of order 4 contains an element of order 2 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your conjecture is false. Probably an explicit counterexample is easy to write down but here's an existence proof that counterexamples are plentiful: asymptotically it's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%E2%80%93Sims_asymptotic_formula) (Higman-Sims) that there are $p^{ \frac{2}{27} n^3 + O(n^{8/3})}$ groups of order $p^n$, for $p$ a prime. The elements of such a group have one of $n+1$ possible orders $1, p, \dots p^n$, and so the number of possible different order profiles of such a group is at most the number of compositions of $p^n$ into at most $n+1$ parts, which is ${p^n + n \choose n}$ which only grows at best like $O(p^{n^2})$ (edit: and see the comments for more on this). So asymptotically there are many more groups of order $p^n$ than there are possible order profiles.

**Edit:** [This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39850/290) contains the explicit counterexample of the Heisenberg group $H_3(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and $C_3^3$ (order $27$, so $p = 3, n = 3$), which are not isomorphic but have the same order profile (all non-identity elements have order $3$). [This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223820/290) to the same question says the smallest counterexamples have order $16$.

**Edit #2:** It is maybe worth saying that the fast growth of the number of groups of order $p^n$ kicks in already for pretty small values of $n$. For $n = 10$ there are about $49$ million groups of order $2^{10} = 1024$ and these account for over $99\%$ of the groups of order $\le 2000$. See, for example, [this blog post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/11/almost_all_of_the_first_50_bil.html). Most of these groups are $2$-step nilpotent so have elements of orders $1, 2, 4$, and so as YCor says in the comments these groups have at most $(2^{10} - 1) + 1 = 1024$ order profiles, so by pigeonhole we know at least some collection of $\approx 49000$ of these groups have the same order profile. Conjecturally "almost all" finite groups are $2$-step nilpotent $2$-groups so this is in some sense "typical."

Comment: I guess this huge number comes from groups of exponent 4, which narrows down the number of "profiles". Actually the analogue for odd $p$ is even simpler, since the huge number of groups of order $p^n$ comes from groups of exponent $p$.

Comment: @YCor: yes, of course, thank you. The lower bound comes from $2$-step nilpotent groups which only have elements of orders $1, 2, 4$ so in fact we only need to count compositions of $2^n$ into at most $3$ parts, so ${2^n + 2 \choose 2}$.

Comment: Rather the number $(2^n)$ of composition $2^n-1$ into two parts, since there's a single element of order 1.